# getting the current cumulative COUNT() for each week

Tags: sql-server

if I have following database records

```
dtAdded         ItemName

...
2014-01-01 12:19:00     Aaasd
2014-01-02 01:19:00     Bbsadsad
2014-01-03 12:19:00     Ccasd
2014-01-04 12:19:00     Ddasd
2014-01-05 12:19:00     Eesadsad
2014-01-06 12:19:00     Ffsadsad
...
2014-02-11 12:19:00     Hasd
2014-02-12 02:19:00     Iasdsad
2014-02-12 12:12:00     Jasd
2014-02-12 04:19:00     Ksadsad
2014-02-12 08:29:00     Lsad
2014-02-13 0911:00      Masdsad
2014-02-13 11:19:00     Nsadsad
...
```

How to return the cumulative item total for every WEEK so it would return something like this (just the last 3-4weeks)

```
DATE        Total
2014-01-26  30  <-- TOTAL ITEM PER THIS SUNDAY
2014-02-02  80  <-- TOTAL ITEM PER THIS SUNDAY
2014-02-09  120 <-- TOTAL ITEM PER THIS SUNDAY
2014-02-14  140 <-- THIS IS TODAY
```

Thank you

Comment: What is DATE in your result? the start day of the week?

Comment: @Paul the date of each Sunday. and the last record, the date is today date.

Comment: How is this different to your previous two questions? Are you just unable to generalize from solutions that people give you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, i tried, basically i want to "merge" those two answers but no luck. I know only basic sql query :)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is something... check if the days fall into the correct week, weekno from the US is different than from Europe for example...

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, dteAdded), DATEPART( wk, dtAdded), count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, dteAdded), DATEPART( wk, dtAdded)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, dteAdded), DATEPART( wk, dtAdded)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @t table (dtAdded datetime, ItemName  varchar(50))

insert into @t
select '2014-01-01 12:19:00','Aaasd' union all
select '2014-01-02 01:19:00','Bbsadsad' union all
select '2014-01-03 12:19:00','Ccasd' union all
select '2014-01-04 12:19:00','Ddasd' union all
select '2014-01-05 12:19:00','Eesadsad' union all
select '2014-01-06 12:19:00','Ffsadsad' union all
select '2014-02-11 12:19:00','Hasd' union all
select '2014-02-12 02:19:00','Iasdsad' union all
select '2014-02-12 12:12:00','Jasd' union all
select '2014-02-12 04:19:00','Ksadsad' union all
select '2014-02-12 08:29:0','Lsad' union all
select '2014-02-13 09:11:00','Masdsad' union all
select '2014-02-13 11:19:00','Nsadsad'

Declare @startdate date='2014-01-26'

Declare @enddate date
select @enddate= max(dtAdded) from @t


;with cte as
(
select @startdate dates  
union all
select dateadd(day,7,dates)
 from cte a where dates<=@enddate
)

Select dates , 
(select count(*) from @t where dtAdded<=a.dates)Total
from cte a
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, here is the code with the actual table name (different from my question above)

```
WITH
CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       cast(floor(cast(LastUpdateDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,LastUpdateDate)+1 as BeginOfWeek,        
       cast(floor(cast(LastUpdateDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,LastUpdateDate)+7 as EndOfWeek
  FROM [linnworks_finaware].[dbo].[StockItems] si
  INNER JOIN [linnworks_finaware].[dbo].[StockLevel] sl  ON si.pkStockID = sl.[fkStockItemId] 
  WHERE sl.[Quantity] > 0
  ),

T AS (
    SELECT
       cast(floor(cast(LastUpdateDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,LastUpdateDate)+1 as BeginOfWeek,        
       cast(floor(cast(LastUpdateDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,LastUpdateDate)+7 as EndOfWeek
  FROM [linnworks_finaware].[dbo].[StockItems] si
  INNER JOIN [linnworks_finaware].[dbo].[StockLevel] sl  ON si.pkStockID = sl.[fkStockItemId] 
  WHERE sl.[Quantity] > 0
  )

SELECT 
MIN(
CASE WHEN GETDATE()<CTE_Dates.EndOfWeek
    THEN GETDATE() 
    ELSE CTE_Dates.EndOfWeek
    END
) as EndOfWeek,
COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM CTE_Dates
INNER JOIN T
    ON CTE_Dates.EndOfWeek >= T.EndOfWeek
GROUP BY CTE_Dates.EndOfWeek
ORDER BY EndOfWeek DESC
```